# In WPF, how do I get the current theme's button background?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In my wpf application, I need to get the theme's button background brush to draw the background of another control.

I have tried referencing PresentationFramework.Aero.dll and using ButtonChrome, but no luck so far.

I've tried using VisualStyleRenderer also, but it seems that this class can be used only to draw the background (I can't get a brush and set it as the background of another control).

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,
Eduardo Melo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done in code by looking up the default button style in the resources :

```
    private static object GetValueFromStyle(object styleKey, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        Style style = Application.Current.TryFindResource(styleKey) as Style;
        while (style != null)
        {
            var setter =
                style.Setters
                    .OfType<Setter>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Property == property);

            if (setter != null)
            {
                return setter.Value;
            }

            style = style.BasedOn;
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...

    this.Background = GetValueFromStyle(typeof(Button), BackgroundProperty) as Brush;
```

If you need to do it in XAML, you can easily create a markup extension from the code above:

```
public class ValueFromStyleExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public ValueFromStyleExtension()
    {
    }

    public object StyleKey { get; set; }
    public DependencyProperty Property { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (StyleKey == null || Property == null)
            return null;
        object value = GetValueFromStyle(StyleKey, Property);
        if (value is MarkupExtension)
        {
            return ((MarkupExtension)value).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static object GetValueFromStyle(object styleKey, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        Style style = Application.Current.TryFindResource(styleKey) as Style;
        while (style != null)
        {
            var setter =
                style.Setters
                    .OfType<Setter>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Property == property);

            if (setter != null)
            {
                return setter.Value;
            }

            style = style.BasedOn;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
Background="{util:ValueFromStyle StyleKey={x:Type Button}, Property=Control.Background}">
```

---

EDIT: fixed `ValueFromStyleExtension` for the case where the value is defined as a `DynamicResource` (or another ME)

Comment: Only one thing: for those getting the "MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknowMarkupExtension" bug, here's a solution: http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/nested-markup-extension-bug

Comment: Yes, that's an annoying bug... It doesn't happen if the ME is defined in a separate assembly

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thomas, only one thing more: if I define it as a DynamicResource, when the system theme changes, the background will change also?

Comment: You mean, if it's defined as a DynamicResource in the style ? No, it won't update automatically. For that the ME would have to return the DynamicResource markup extension, but for some reason it didn't seem to work when I tried...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Can you edit your code above to include the return of the DynamicResource? I really don't know anything about MarkupExtensions, and I think it can help me understand it better.

Comment: Like I said, I tried and it didn't work; I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Ok. I tried an approach using Triggers, but I gave up, in the end. The frequency of an user changing themes aren't high, anyway. Thanks!