# Default TabItem Background Color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, systemcolors

I want to set the background color of a TabItem Header (TabItem.Background) if certain content is not set in the tab.  To accomplish this, I have a Brush property in my ViewModel that is bound to the Background property of the TabItem.  However, I'm not sure how to get/create the default TabItem background brush.

```
public Brush TabItemBrush
{
    get
    {
        return IsContentSet ? DefaultTabItemBrush : Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
    }
}
```

```xml
<TabItem Header="Some Header" Background="{Binding TabItemBrush, Mode=OneWay}">
```

I would like the **DefaultTabItemBrush** brush to match the other TabItems so if the Theme changes all the TabItems will still look the same.

Is the default brush available in SystemColors?

Using C# / .NET 3.5

Comment: I found an acceptable solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198500/in-wpf-how-do-i-get-the-current-themes-button-background/4198971#comment-8027648

Comment: Did you ever find out what the default brush is from SystemColors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from [In WPF, how do I get the current theme's button background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198500/in-wpf-how-do-i-get-the-current-themes-button-background/4198971#comment-8027648)

Then in my code looks something like:

```
public Brush TabItemBrush
{
    get
    {
        return IsContentSet ?  (Brush)UIUtilities.GetValueFromStyle(typeof(TabItem), Control.BackgroundProperty) : Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
    }
}
```

```xml
<TabItem Header="Some Header" Background="{Binding TabItemBrush, Mode=OneWay}">
```

When IsContentSet == true it will use the default brush and when false some other brush in this case LightSKyBlue